# Android cursor problems "Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it."

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

I want to get the photo name from SQL database,then get the photo from drawable file and link the photo to a ImageView item which is inside a ListView what is the problem with following code, Please help me fix it, thank you

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HotProduct extends ListActivity {

    private ProductSQLiteHelper sqlHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase infodb;
    private String[] columnsToSelect;
    private String[] columnsToSelect2;
    private Cursor infoCursor;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dbAdapter;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dbAdapter2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hotproduct_middle_page);
        columnsToSelect = new String[] {
                ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_ID,
                ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_NAME,
                ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_BRAND,
                ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_PRICE


        };




        Resources res = getResources();
        Log.v("Res:",String.valueOf(res));


//        setTitle("Hot Product");



        sqlHelper = new ProductSQLiteHelper(this);

        infodb = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();


        Cursor infoCursor= infodb.rawQuery("SELECT photo FROM phone", null);
        ImageView moviePoster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.productPhoto);
        infoCursor.moveToFirst();
        if (!infoCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            if (infoCursor.getInt(infoCursor.getColumnIndex(String.valueOf(ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_HOT))) == 1) {
                res = this.getResources();
                String posterResourceName = infoCursor.getString(infoCursor.getColumnIndex(ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_PHOTO));
                Log.v("resource name",posterResourceName);
                int resId = res.getIdentifier(posterResourceName, "drawable", getPackageName());
                moviePoster.setImageResource(resId);
            }
        }

        String columnsToDisplay[] = {
                ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_NAME,
                ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_BRAND,
                ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_PRICE
//                ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_PHOTO
        };


        int mappingToView[] = {
                R.id.productName,
                R.id.productBrand,
                R.id.productPrice
//                R.id.productPhoto
        };





        String args[] = {"1"};
        infoCursor = infodb.query(ProductSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,columnsToSelect," hot = ? ",args,null,null,null);

        String posterResourceName = infoCursor.getString(infoCursor.getColumnIndex("photo"));
        Log.v("resource name",posterResourceName);
        dbAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.hotproduct_middle_page_row,infoCursor,columnsToDisplay,mappingToView,0);


        setListAdapter(dbAdapter);



        }




}
```

I found that the problems appear in

```
      Cursor infoCursor= infodb.rawQuery("SELECT photo FROM phone", null);
        ImageView moviePoster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.productPhoto);
        infoCursor.moveToFirst();
        if (!infoCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            if (infoCursor.getInt(infoCursor.getColumnIndex(String.valueOf(ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_HOT))) == 1) {
                res = this.getResources();
                String posterResourceName = infoCursor.getString(infoCursor.getColumnIndex(ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_PHOTO));
                Log.v("resource name",posterResourceName);
                int resId = res.getIdentifier(posterResourceName, "drawable", getPackageName());
                moviePoster.setImageResource(resId);
            }
        }
```

Comment: i think you have to check before write this lines `String args[] = {"1"};
        infoCursor = infodb.query(ProductSQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,columnsToSelect," hot = ? ",args,null,null,null);
` , that `if (cur.moveToFirst()) {  String posterResourceName = infoCursor.getString(infoCursor.getColumnIndex("photo")); }` please try like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android cursor error - "make sure cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483644/android-cursor-error-make-sure-cursor-is-initialized-correctly-before-accessi)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to a `getColumnIndex` not finding the specified column and thus returning -1 (as it does when the column is not a column). The underlying cause is that you are creating a Cursor with a single column yet in your code you are trying to access 2 columns i.e.

- `infoCursor.getInt(infoCursor.getColumnIndex(String.valueOf(ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_HOT)))`
- `infoCursor.getString(infoCursor.getColumnIndex(ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_PHOTO))`

The Cursor will contain just 1 column, the photo column.

I would suggest changing the SELECT clause to **`"SELECT * FROM phone"`**, this will then create a Cursor with ALL columns from the table.

However, there is an additional flaw with the code in that you are not checking the result of the `moveToFirst`.

If the Cursor is empty then `moveToFirst` will return false. As the Cursor will not be *after the last* any attempt to retrieve data from the Cursor will fail as there is no data.

I would suggest amending your code to :-

```
        Cursor infoCursor= infodb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM phone", null);
        ImageView moviePoster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.productPhoto);
        while (infoCursor.moveToNext()) {
            if (infoCursor.getInt(infoCursor.getColumnIndex(String.valueOf(ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_HOT))) == 1) {
                res = this.getResources();
                String posterResourceName = infoCursor.getString(infoCursor.getColumnIndex(ProductSQLiteHelper.PRODUCT_PHOTO));
                Log.v("resource name",posterResourceName);
                int resId = res.getIdentifier(posterResourceName, "drawable", getPackageName());
                moviePoster.setImageResource(resId);
            }
        }
```

You may have to write code to handle an empty cursor.

Comment: I have just tried your code.... I found that the problems still there,  but BTW thanks for your answering

Comment: If you edit your question and add the stack trace from the log then the issue could be analysed.